# Why checkValidty() returns false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur, checkvalidity

I have focus/blur function that disables submit button on `focus` then on `blur` checks if value is different than original value(I keep original value in data attribute for existing records) and checks if is valid. However I noticed one situation where my code breaks. For example in my example if you enter `07AB` code function will return false and you will see the message `Code already exist.`. Then if I enter `07ab` (just entered code value with lower case `a` and `b`) then function won't be triggered and user is able to submit the form. I did use `console.log()` to check if statement inside of the blur function and appears that `checkValidty()` returns `true` for `07AB` but returns `false` for `07ab`. Here is code example:

```js
var codes = ["07AB","110A","117B","0316"]
$(".check-value").focus(function() {
  var submitBtn = $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").prop("disabled", true); //Disable submit button on field focus.
}).blur(function() {
  var fldObj = $(this),
    frmMessage = $(this).closest("form").find(".message-submit"),
    submitBtn = $(this).closest("form").find(":submit");

  if (String(fldObj.val()) !== String(fldObj.data("current")) && fldObj.get(0).checkValidity()) {
   console.log("Check value.");
    if ($.inArray(fldObj.val(), codes) === -1) {
      fldObj.get(0).setCustomValidity("");
    } else {
      fldObj.get(0).setCustomValidity("Code already exists!");
    }
    submitBtn.prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    fldObj.get(0).setCustomValidity("");
    submitBtn.prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="code"><span class="label label-primary">Code:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control check-value" name="frm_code" id="frm_code" data-current="" data-fldname="code" maxlength="4" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}$" title="Code field allows alphanumeric characters only (must be four characters length) - no other special characters"
      placeholder="Example: 07AB" required>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div id="frm_message" class="alert message-submit"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase and Uppercase letters are different characters with different ascii / utf / latin / etc numerical associations. To solve your problem, either use a regular expression to check equality, or use .toLowerCase or .toUpperCase on your input.

```
if ($.inArray(fldObj.val().toUpperCase(), codes) === -1) { //added toUpperCase()
  fldObj.get(0).setCustomValidity("");
} else {
  fldObj.get(0).setCustomValidity("Code already exists!");
}
```

Comment: I use `pattern` with regular expression. You can see that `.checkValidty()` triggers that regular expression. Problem is that if I enter `07AB` that will return `true` but if I enter same value again `07AB` or `07ab` then returns `false`.